# Sha1 encryption of password when creating SOAP request in c#

Tags: c#, soap, sha1

Im trying to integrate using SOAP to a web service but I'm getting stucked in the authorization part, and more specifically when creating sha1 encrypted password. 
Documentation for this specific authorization can be found at https://www.beautyfort.com/api/docs/AuthHeader-t1

I have been searching the net trying to find different ways to create the password but none seems to generate the same password as the example in the documentation page.

```
string testDateString = "2015-07-08T11:31:53+01:00";
string testNonce = "186269";
string testSecret = "Ok4IWYLBHbKn8juM1gFPvQxadieZmS2";

SHA1CryptoServiceProvider sha1Hasher = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
byte[] hashedDataBytes = sha1Hasher.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(testNonce + testDateString + testSecret));
string Sha1Password = Convert.ToBase64String(hashedDataBytes);
```

The input variables is from documentation page. According to the documentation the password should get the value "ZDg3MTZiZTgwYTMwYWY4Nzc4OGFjMmZhYjA5YzM3MTdlYmQ1M2ZkMw=="
but the code I am using is generating "2HFr6Aowr4d4isL6sJw3F+vVP9M=".

Anyone have a bright idea of what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Do they also use UTF-8?

Comment: Hmm. Do not know, but I still get the same (faulty) password value if I change to Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes instead.

Comment: Confirmed. I just tried to maybe find the correct Algo by brute force, but none of the SHA CryptoProviders provide the correct length (nor value of course).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a wild guess that maybe the output of "sha1()" in the documention psuedo-code was a hex-string (like sha1() in PHP, etc), and that seems to output the expected password.

Updated code:

```
string testDateString = "2015-07-08T11:31:53+01:00";
string testNonce = "186269";
string testSecret = "Ok4IWYLBHbKn8juM1gFPvQxadieZmS2";

SHA1CryptoServiceProvider sha1Hasher = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
byte[] hashedDataBytes = sha1Hasher.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(testNonce + testDateString + testSecret));

var hexString = BitConverter.ToString(hashedDataBytes).Replace("-", string.Empty).ToLower();
string Sha1Password = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(hexString));
```

Comment: Absolutely brilliant! Thank you!